# Using JSON in After Effects to set the entry point of layers or compositions

Tags: json, after-effects

I have a video template, made of ~30 compositions, named 1 to 30.

Each of the 30 compositions is made of one layer only, and that layer is an .mp4 file, of which the composition only extracts a certain segment, say 5 seconds.

So composition 1 is a 5-second long comp made of the layer 1.mp4, and 1.mp4 is a 2-minute long footage, for which I choose an entry point at 1:02 so that my composition shows that footage only from 1:02 to 1:07. (please see image below)

Whenever my client send me a new set of 30 .mp4 pieces footage to place in my 30 compositions:

- I rename them 1.mp4 to 30.mp4 to replace my old files (a Python script does the job)
- I *manually* set the starting time of each footage to the desired time (eg. -1:02, as shown in the blue circle in the image below).

My question is the following: **is there a way for me to use a .json file to set the entry points of my ~30 .mp4 files in bulk**?

I work with AE 2019.

Thank you!

[image: Screen from AE]

Answer (score 0):

Why a json file? As I understand it, you want to automate the process of changing the start times of each layer 1 in your many comps, right?
The following .js or .jsx script (save **as plain text** with either of those file extensions and run from ae) will work to do what you want, but you **must**

1. know the time in decimal (not frames, not timecode!) to use. It worked for me to what you're asking on my test project in which the comps were at 30 fps, using the default -1.1 input.
2. Choose Start Point ("Yes" button) to do what I think you want (you can also do inPoint, which *trims* each layer 1)
3. Select the comps to work on before running

Here's the code:

```
var everyItem = app.project.items;
selectedComps = new Array();
for (var i = everyItem.length; i >= 1; i--) {
    eyeTem = everyItem[i];
    if ((eyeTem instanceof CompItem) && eyeTem.selected) {
        selectedComps[selectedComps.length] = eyeTem;
    }
}
c=confirm("Shift Start Point of each Layer 1? Yes for Starting Point, No for inPoint (inPoint trims)");
p=prompt("Enter time in seconds:", "-1.1");
pNumber = 0;
if (p == null) {//User Canceled

}else{
    killit=false;
    try {
        pNumber = eval(p);
    } catch(e) {
        killit=true;
    }
    app.beginUndoGroup("Adjust Layer 1 Start or In");
    if (c==true) {//Yes - starting point
        for (var n = (selectedComps.length-1); n >= 0; n--) {
            item = selectedComps[n];
            item.layers[1].startTime = pNumber;
        }
    }else{//no - trim in
        if (pNumber >= 0) {//cannot be negative
            for (var n = (selectedComps.length-1); n >= 0; n--) {
                item = selectedComps[n];
                item.layers[1].inPoint = pNumber;
            }
        }else{
            alert("You entered a negative number for an inPoint trim. That won't do anything");
        }
    }
    app.endUndoGroup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - will try and report :)